# Speed up compilation by (pre-)compiling chapters separately?

Tags: compiling, include

I am writing a long document with many chapters. They are all included from a root document using `\input{chapterX.tex}` etc. Compiling everything takes pretty long.

As a workaround to make compilation faster, I typically comment out most `\input` commands and include only the chapter I'm currently working on. But that's a bad method because then the references to chapters that are not currently included won't work, and the table of contents is almost empty.

I'm wondering if there is a method that does precompilation? Ideally, it would detect that, while I am working on `chapter1.tex`, nothing in `chapter2.tex` etc. has changed, and reuse the results from previous compilation runs.

Is that possible? It would be like separate compilation units in languages like `C`.

Comment: For others finding this in the future, consider using the package `newclude` if you want to use `\include` and `\includeonly`, as two answers suggested.  Standard `\include` is very finicky about component source file locations; `newclude` redefines it to avoid path problems, and provides other potentially useful benefits.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't precompile chapters, but you can use the `\includeonly` mechanism to ensure that your cross-references and page numbers stay correct while choosing to only include parts of your source.

Answer (score 18):

Extending Joseph's answer a bit: This mean that you use `\include` and *not* `\input` for including the desired chapters. See [here](http://user.medunigraz.at/alexander.binder/texhelp/ltx-245.html) for example usage.

Comment: Oops, missed the use of `\input` in the question: thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :). This site really rocks!

Comment: And here is a page that explains the crucial difference between `\include` and `\input`: http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~rdale/resources/writingnotes/latexstruct.html . To summarise, each file that you `\include` will generate a separate `*.aux` file, and those `*.aux` files are always read.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Comment: @BrantheBlessed, the example has a broken link.

Comment: The link yields a 404. Care to update it? :)

Answer (score 1):

The above answers helped me a lot and I used the `\includeonly` method for a while, but was too bothered by having to manually edit the `\includeonly` line with the correct files. I then realized that this work could easily be automated and I wrote a small script that does it for me and that I share with you here:

My idea was to include only files that were modified since the last creation of the pdf (which in practice is what I want). To do this, I input in the preamble a file **only.tex**. This file which will contain the line with the `\includeonly` will be generated automatically by my script.

Hence, my main tex file looks like:

**main.tex**

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\input{only.tex}
\begin{document}
\include{fileA.tex}
\include{fileB.tex}
\end{document}
```

To generate the **only.tex** file, my script retrieves the last modification date of the pdf, and writes in **only.tex** the name of all the .tex files that are newer than this date (this is done using the **find -newer** command)

**diff.sh**

```sh
TARGET=only.tex
LAST=$(stat --format='%Y' build/$1.pdf) # last modification of the pdf file
elapsed=$(echo "$(date +%s) - $LAST" | bc) # number of seconds elapsed since
echo "last modification was $elapsed seconds ago"

printf "\includeonly{" > $TARGET
for i in $(find . -name "*.tex" -newermt "$elapsed seconds ago"); do
    file="$(basename $i)"
    # we skip the generated file, and the main .tex file which is an
    # argument of this script
    if [ "$file" != "$1.tex" ] && [ "$file" != $TARGET ]; then
        printf "$file," >> $TARGET
    fi
done
printf "}" >> $TARGET
```

This script can very probably be improved, made more robust or more concise, but I never felt the need for it personally.

Finally, all that remains to do is to wrap the whole thing within a Makefile
that allows me to switch between partial (**make**) and full compilation (**make full**).

**Makefile**

```
partial:
    ./diff.sh main
    pdflatex main.tex

full :
    echo "" > only.tex
    pdflatex main.tex
```

When compiling partially, we first call the **diff.sh** script, and then compile normally while the full compilation consists of simply overwriting the **only.tex** file with an empty string, then compiling normally.