# How to create separate parts in a long paper?

Tags: sectioning, parts

I have a long paper which includes several chapters.
I want to add a separator between certain subsets of chapters, which will have numeral counts, and will include a title taking the whole page, as a separator between these chapters. These separators should be included in the table of contents, with font which is slightly larger.

For example:

```
Part I: Related work (whole page, centered)
chapter 1
chapter 2

Part II: Our Method (whole page, centered)
chapter 3
chapter 4
```

and so on.

How can I set this up?

I have seen this done in dissertations, and I am pretty sure there must be some command or type of "section" which is at a higher level than a chapter, but I can't seem to find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking for the `\part` sectioning macro. You need to use the `report` or better `book` class or similar for this.

```
\part{Related work}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}

\part{Our Method}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
```

I would highly recommend you to place your chapters into separate `.tex` files and include them with [`\include`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include/250#250). See also [`\includeonly`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1989/speed-up-compilation-by-pre-compiling-chapters-separately/1991#1991).

The so called [*koma-script*](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle provides some alternative report (scrreprt) and book (scrbook) classes which allow for many customisations including modifing the part page. For example you can place some text on them, e.g. a quote or abstract, which is rather difficult with the standard classes.

Comment: Your second sentence (about the need to use `report` or `book`) is incorrect -- the `\part` macro is also defined in `article` and similar classes.

Comment: @lockstep: Yes, but `\chapter` isn't and I assumed he has `\chapter`s in the `\include` files.