# Kile takes a long time to run PDFLaTeX for my thesis

Tags: chapters, thesis, kile, performance

It takes ~15-30 seconds to run PDFLaTeX for my PhD thesis.  This is killing my productivity.

Each included chapter is called, e.g., `\include{theory}`, and the relevant .tex file starts with the respective `\chapter{Theory}`.

A single change in one chapter causes PDFLaTeX to rebuild all chapters; this takes a long time.  **Does Kile have a built-in way to only "recompile" changed chapters**, a la `make` on Linux, so I don't have to wait so long for minor edits?

Details:

- The thesis is only about 100 pages long so far.
- There are some large photos included (necessary for being able to zoom on specific features).  The whole pdf is ~12 MB right now.
- Quickpreview returns with errors since I include graphics and .sty files (it works for very small snippets only).
- My project's main .tex file consists of only `\usepackage` commands, `\include` statements and a handful of other commands (`frontmatter`, `tableofcontents`, `backmatter`, etc).

If I cannot fix this I will have to make ~5-10 separate projects for different chapters, then concatenate them all at the end.  This is undesirable because there are cross-chapter label/references to images and other shared resources across chapters.

Has anybody come across this and solved the problem?

Comment: ule of thumb, the longer the thesis the longer the compile time. The last thesis i was compiling took 18 minutes on my machine for a full run.

Comment: 15-30 seconds? I get that easily on one chapter of my thesis...

Comment: There are people on the site who remember it taking 15 _minutes_ to load `article`, let alone do any work!

Comment: Nothing automatic I think, though you could of course use `\includeonly{filename}` to compile just one `include`d file.

Comment: @JosephWright Those people must be really really old, aren't they? ;-)

Comment: @TorbjørnT., Yes!! This is exactly what I was looking for.  If you post as an answer I will mark accepted.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Similar questions has been asked before, e.g. [Speed up compilation by (pre-)compiling chapters separately?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1991) and [Does LaTeX have to reprocess included files that haven't changed?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55610) so I guess we can rather close as duplicate.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., fair enough.  We can close as duplicate, but this may not help people searching for long compile times if they don't know `\includeonly` exists (e.g., me 1 hour ago).  Thoughts?

Comment: Google will find your question, people will see it as well as the link to the *dupe to come*.

Comment: if you're happy with the way the images are placed and behaving in a chapter, you can suppress inclusion in an interim compilation by applying the `[draft]` option on either the `\documentclass` or the relevant `\usepackage` line for graphics.  by "suppress" i mean that the image itself won't be included, but that the proper space is left, with the name of the file printed as a place marker.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, yes!  Another great answer.  I'm not sure why tex.stackexchange.com users are putting these answers in comments, but I will copy them below.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., see @barbarbeeton's answer for an example of something that answers the heart of this question but not the linked ones.  Please use discretion to closed/mark-as-dup the thread (I only seem to be able to `share` `edit` `delete` `flag`).

Comment: @user1717828 -- i put my suggestion in a comment because i didn't (and don't) think it is a complete answer.  but i noticed that none of the linked answers (these should almost always be in cmments) mentioned `draft` so i did, because you specifically mentioned large graphics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you think that including the large images is what's taking most time,
process just the images and enough surrounding text to make sure they're doing
what you want them to do.  then add `[draft]` using one of these methods in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[draft]{...}
\usepackage[draft]{...}
```

this will suppress loading and processing of the images, but will leave a space of the
proper size in the proper location, with the name of the file printed as a place marker.

remember to remove the `draft` for the final run, and be resigned to the fact that
this run will probably take a *long* time.

to compile a book piecemeal, a chapter at a time, put each chapter in a separate file,
and call them in with `\include`.  then use `\includeonly{...}` in the preamble to
specify which chapter(s) should be processed in a particular run.  this will make use
of the `.aux` files for other chapters already processed, so that cross-references
will be resolved properly.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to avoid the `draft` option of the `graphicx` package, you could duplicate all your images with lower resolution copies, thus you retain the actual images with their respective sizes, however, due to the lower quality the resulting pdf will be smaller and compiling will probably be faster. During writing you probably do not need the high-end quality of your images, but it is not too bad to have them there instead of the empty rectangles.

- copy your images folder to `imagesHighQ`
- put low-quality copies of your images into the images folder

When you are done, delete or rename the images folder; and rename `imagesHighQ`. Run the final compilation.